# Getting error while binding a socket

Tags: python, sockets, python-2.7, networking, server

I am scripting a server to use at many things, gaming, data-transfer, chatting etc.

My problem is i am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "server.py", line 11, in <module>
s.bind((host, port))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
TypeError: an integer is required
```

I am at the beginning of my server script so far and i scripted many networking scripts before. There shouldnt be any problem. I tried this script both on my local and on my servers and still same resuly and the exact same error. I will really appreciate any kind of help.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# This is server file

import socket

# server & connection settings
host = '127.0.0.1'      
port = '5002'
s = socket.socket() # Creating socket object
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(10)
# server & connection settings

while True:
    c,addr = s.accept()                         # Establish connection with clients.
    print 'Got connection from ', addr                  # Print ip adress of the recently connected client.
    c.send('You succesfully established connection with our servers.')  # Send socket to the client.
    print 'Socket had been sent to the client: ', addr          # Print to the server console that we succesfully established connection with the client
    c.close()                               # Close the client connection. Bye, bye! /// Will delete this part when the time come
```

Comment: port should be of type integer. change line port = '5002' to port = 5002

Comment: oh god how did i miss it, i cant believe to myself. Thank you so much!